# Questions about Seemingly Unrelated Regression when all covariates are the same, but Y is different

Tags: hypothesis-testing, econometrics, generalized-least-squares, seemingly-unrelated-regressions, simultaneous-equation

Assuming I was estimating the same regression model, but had two dependent variables. Say one is income for women, and one is income for men. I want to understand if I understand the reason for using seemingly unrelated regression in this case:

1. Is it true that since the x's are the same, then the coefficients should be the same as if estimating both separately, and the standard errors for a particular coefficient also remain the same?

2.Seemingly unrelated regressions in this case should only hold weight if the errors are correlated across equations, and I wish to test whether the coefficient on one x is the same as that on another? i.e.for:
$Y_1 = X\beta_1 + \epsilon_1$
and
$Y_2 = X\beta_2 + \epsilon_2$

where y is different but x is the same, and I want to test if $\beta_1=\beta_2$, does Seemingly unrelated regressions main help come from estimation of a covariance matrix that consistency estimates the correlation between equations, i.e $cov(\beta_1,\beta_2)$? so if this term is zero, I can literally just construct a t test where the standard error = $standard error (\beta_1)$ + $standard error (\beta_2)$?

3. Does Seemingly unrelated regression become relevant in because if I am using the same dataset/observations to estimate the two equations, then there is reason to believe that an error for observation i in equation 1 is correlated with an error for observation i in equation 2? (e.g. if i= state, then the error for New York in equation one is likely correlated with the error in New York for equation 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the concept of SURE isn't relevant in this case.
Each individual in your data is either male or female (I assume), thus the two regressions have disjoint sets of observations. SURE is used when the same observations are used in two (or more) separate regressions but have different outcome variables.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance I would say that you don't have two different DVs, you have one DV and a factor (the gender) on top of the other covariates. In particular, I don't see the point of using SUR in your case: since men and women make separate datasets, you're not really using the same data twice.

The coefficients are not necessarily the same for men and women, which you can test/detect by including the interaction between the gender and the covariates in your linear model.